# Открытие киви с параметрами из другого приложения

Tags: java, android, qiwi

Как открыть Qiwi Wallet с установленными параметрами (номер счета) из другого приложения?
Кнопку, на кнопку слушатель - это понятно.
А сам код для этого какой?

Comment: Ну... интент, вестимо, надо некий послать... А что в доках киви на сей счёт говорят?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а она есть? Я вот не нашел.

Comment: Я не знаю - ни разу этим не интересовался)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а не будет ли сходным интент для звонилки?

Comment: Возможно... Надо, по идее, узнать с каким ключом какое значение в интен пихнуть при запуске.